# How to make it so the Virtual Machine doesn't store its files in the real computer

Tags: virtual-machine, destruction

My friends and i had a idea that we could do our own version of Windows Destruction. Except we don't know how to make it so the real computer itself doesn't get those viruses too. How could we do this?

Comment: That's not how files work.  You need to be concerned about network.

Answer (score 2):

This specifically mentions VirtualBox, but much of this applies of the majority of other VM software.

The vast majority of VM hosts store the data in a virtual hard drive, which is often a single file.  Because of this, the actual data is there, but cannot be executed, and therefore cannot cause harm to your computer.  As @SLacks said, you need to be sure to disable any shared folders, and be absolutely sure that they indeed are disabled.  VirtualBox documentation for guest additions is [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).

On a side note, as a person who has experience with malware, I would highly advise against running any live samples unless you know exactly what you're doing.  Even if you do, there is still always the chance to cause harm to your computer.  If you really want to, install Windows on an old computer and do that instead.  Live malware is not a joke, though I will admit that it can be fun sometimes.

Back to the main topic, you need to check over every setting in the VM to disable any methods of file transfers between the host and the client machine.

[Shared folder settings for VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdp49.png)